# Basic question on irreducibility

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $f(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ in $\mathbb{Z[x]}$

$f$ does not have a root hence it is irreducible.

So the only factorisations of $f(x)$ are ones that contain units, i.e.

$1 \cdot (x^2 + x + 1)$

and

$-1 \cdot -(x^2 + x + 1)$

So irreducibility is like an abstraction of the concept of prime numbers in the integers, yes?

Comment: I'd say "generalization" instead of abstraction, but yes, that's the right idea. Prime elements of rings are abstractions of the prime integers.

Answer (score 2):

There is a concept of a prime element of a commutative ring $R$. An element $a\in R$ is prime if for every $b,c\in R$, $(a|bc)\Rightarrow (a|b \vee a|c )$. Being prime implies being irreducible but primeness is stronger. These two notions are equivalent in any [UFD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain).